# How to put "form" in same line?

Tags: css

So what im trying to achive is that i have something like this:

```
----------------------------------
     Weekend: from 9am to 1pm
     Summer:  from 8am to 3pm
     Winter:  from 9am to 1pm
----------------------------------
```

So that i have align left side and right side.
This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7vdbLcL9/5/

```
    <div class="working-time">

        <div class="working-time-details">  
        <div class="working-time-title">WORKING HOURS</div>
            <div><span>WINTER:</span>  <span>from 9am to 4pm</span></div>
            <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span>from 9am to 1pm</span></div>
            <div><span>SUMMER:</span>  <span>from 9am to 7pm</span></div>
            <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span>from 10am to 2pm</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like tabular data to me, so why not use a table?

Comment: @AlexChar its not align left and right side

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7vdbLcL9/11/

Comment: you can use <table> to quicly solve the problem, could look dirty but it's only a few line of code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xhev1w6b/

Comment: @j08691 I think it would make sense to replace `<td class="right">` with `<th>` to provide extra semantics. As a bonus, it would be easier to style `th` and `td` separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the first span width with this code `.working-time-details div span:first-child{display: inline-block;width: 85px;}`

```css
.working-time{
  width: 95%;
  border:1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  color:gray;
}
.working-time-details{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.working-time-title{
  color:white;
  margin-top:20%;
  margin-bottom:10%;
}
.working-time-title span{
  float:right;
  width: 100px;
}

.working-time-details div span:first-child{display: inline-block;width: 85px;}
```

```html
<div class="working-time">
  <div class="working-time-details"> 
    <div class="working-time-title">WORKING HOURS</div>
    <div><span>WINTER:</span>  <span>from 9am to 4pm</span></div>
    <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span>from 9am to 1pm</span></div>
    <div><span>SUMMER:</span>  <span>from 9am to 7pm</span></div>
    <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span>from 10am to 2pm</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/q0dexosq/

**HTML**

```
<div class="working-time">

    <div class="working-time-details">  
        <div class="working-time-title">WORKING HOURS</div>
        <div class="clear"><span class="left">WINTER:</span>  <span class="right">from 9am to 4pm</span></div>
        <div class="clear"><span class="left">WEEKEND:</span> <span class="right">from 9am to 1pm</span></div>
        <div class="clear"><span class="left">SUMMER:</span>  <span class="right">from 9am to 7pm</span></div>
        <div class="clear"><span class="left">WEEKEND:</span> <span class="right">from 10am to 2pm</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.working-time{
    width: 95%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    color:gray;
}
.working-time-details{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 250px;
}
.working-time-title{
    color:black;
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/7vdbLcL9/12/ ?

I have just added a selector: working-time-details span.time and a class of "time".

CSS:

```
.working-time{
    width: 95%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    color:gray;
}
.working-time-details{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    line-height: 22px;
    width: 228px;
}
.working-time-title{
    color:white;
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}
.working-time-details span.time {
    float: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="working-time">

            <div class="working-time-details">  
            <div class="working-time-title">WORKING HOURS</div>
                <div><span>WINTER:</span>  <span class="time">from 9am to 4pm</span></div>
                <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span class="time">from 9am to 1pm</span></div>
                <div><span>SUMMER:</span>  <span class="time">from 9am to 7pm</span></div>
                <div><span>WEEKEND:</span> <span class="time">from 10am to 2pm</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to each of the spans and float one left, and float the other to the right. That way you don't need to worry about having anything fixed width.

```
<div><span class="float-left">WINTER:</span>  <span class="float-right">from 9am to 4pm</span></div>
<div><span class="float-left">WEEKEND:</span> <span class="float-right">from 9am to 1pm</span></div>
<div><span class="float-left">SUMMER:</span>  <span class="float-right">from 9am to 7pm</span></div>
<div><span class="float-left">WEEKEND:</span> <span class="float-right">from 10am to 2pm</span></div>
```

And here is the corresponding css:

```
.float-right {
    float: right;
}
.float-left {
    float: left;
}
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7vdbLcL9/13/